# C# math library (System.Numerics vs Math.NET)

Tags: c#, graphics, game-engine, numeric, math.net

I'm trying to make my own game engine for learning purposes, but I'm also trying to make something that is optimized and is capable of handling a diverse amount of `cross-platform` games.

That said, I'm now at a point where I need to choose a math library to deal with SIMD operations for graphics rendering, and I can't decide on which one should I pick.

After some research, I've found that Math.NET seems pretty good for the job, but the native `System.Numerics` seems somewhat easier to use and does not require a third-party dependency.

I've seen some posts that claimed `System.Numerics` was slow, but they were all long past the due date (3 to 6 years ago), so I don't think they have reliable results anymore.

So my question is, especially now that `.NET Core 3.0` has been released, has `System.Numerics` become reliable enough that it can be used for heavy graphical computation, or should I forget about it and go for something like `Math.NET`?

Finally, would there be a better alternative that I haven't considered? I'll admit that it would be nice if there was a library which provided some kind of abstraction over platform-specific code (but it wouldn't be a problem to write it myself either)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a case of speed vs precision. Sometimes math calculations in games can get away with certain approximations, like in case of classic [Fast Inverse Square Root calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) , rather than traditionally calculating it according to the formula.

It also seems that `Math.NET` started as a more feature-rich alternative to `System.Numerics`, with the later not being developed for high-speed computational purposes. With recent developments, `System.Numerics` might have caught up with `Math.NET`. Ultimately, profiling will help you find out which one is better.

Also a note - Unity having it's old math library, as well as the new SIMD-enabled math library both are a sign that maybe `System.Numerics` isn't that performant - but that's just an observation.